# Grep and find to get the last match in multiple files

Tags: grep, tail

Assume two files with the following content:

```
$ cat ttest1.txt 
x = 1
x = 3
y = 5
$ cat ttest2.txt 
x = 4
x = 10
y = 3
```

I would like to recursively grep the files for `x` and print the last instance in each file. So, the desired output is

```
ttest1.txt:x = 3
ttest2.txt:x = 10
```

The following combination of `grep` and `tail` works for one file but not multiple files.

```
$ grep x ttest1.txt 
x = 1
x = 3
$ grep x ttest1.txt | tail -n 1
x = 3
$ grep -r x ttest* | tail -n 1
ttest2.txt:x = 10
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Is using `grep` a must, or other tools could work ?

Comment: Note that `grep -r x ttest*` doesn't recursively search for files whose name starts with `ttest`. The `ttest*` is first expanded by the shell to the list of file *in the current directory* whose name starts with `ttest` and then pass those to `grep`. If any of those are of type *directory*, then `grep` will recurse into them to find files (of any name). To `grep` in regular files whose name starts with `ttest` at any depth, you'd need zsh and `grep -H -- x **/ttest*(D.)` or use `find . -name 'ttest*' -type f -exec grep -H x {} +`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
grep -r x ttest*
```

you get a single stream with

```
ttest1.txt:x = 1
ttest1.txt:x = 3
ttest2.txt:x = 4
ttest2.txt:x = 10
```

If you `tail -1` that, you get the `ttest2.txt:x = 10`. That is as expected.

But you want the `grep | tail` combination done on each separate file, not on the consolidated stream. So: do it on each separate file.

```
for f in ttest* ; do
    grep x "$f" | tail -n 1
done
```

Comment: That works but it doesn't print file name.

Comment: @mahmood you can add the option `-H` (`--with-filename`) to the grep command to print the file name. But you need GNU grep to do so.

Comment: ... or just add `/dev/null` as an extra operand at the end.  `grep` will always display the filename if given more than a single pathname to operate on.  What the answer does not do is to search recursively, but to be fair, the code in the question did not do that either (unless `ttest*` happened to match a directory name).

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`, you could use an regexp string (see [Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html)), remember the last match of each input file and print it:

```
$ awk -v regex="x" 'FNR==1 && m!=""{print m;m=""} 
        $0 ~ regex{m=FILENAME ":" $0}
        END{if (m!="")print m}' ttest*
ttest1.txt:x = 3
ttest2.txt:x = 10
```

Recursively in combination with `find`:

```
$ find . -name 'ttest*' -type f -exec awk -v regex="x" '
        FNR==1 && m!=""{print m;m=""}
        $0 ~ regex{m=FILENAME ":" $0}
        END{if (m!="")print m}' {} +
./ttest1.txt:x = 3
./ttest2.txt:x = 10
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -sn '/x/h; $ { x; F; p; }' ttest*
```

Output:

```
ttest1.txt
x = 3
ttest2.txt
x = 10
```

Pass this through `paste -d: - -` if you want the results on one line. In case you don't want output from files that do not contain `x` include a check after the `x`-change command, e.g.: `{ x; /./ { F; p; z; }; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing that:

```
grep  x <yourpath>*  | tac | awk  'BEGIN{FS=":"};seen!=$1{print $0;seen=$1}'
```

tac inverts the grep results in preparation to the awk operation, which in turn prints only the first occurrence in each file